# Quiz software like The Guardian's?

Tags: recommendations

I would like to know if there is any quiz software like The Guardian's, e.g.:

http://www.guardian.co.uk/world/quiz/2010/aug/24/1

Features needed are

- the ability to feed in a variable list of questions
- the ability to show the answers to the questions on the question form itself
- the option to see the answers or try again (with the previous answers inserted)
- show the users their score

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Zoho Challenge Quiz Maker](http://www.zoho.com/challenge/quiz-maker.html). You can embed the quizzes you create there in your website